# This code is too inefficient, how can I increase memory and execution efficiency?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, optimization

I'm trying to complete the following challenge: https://app.codesignal.com/challenge/ZGBMLJXrFfomwYiPs.
I have written code that appears to work, however, it is so inefficient that it fails the test (too long to execute and uses too much memory). Are there any ways I can make this more efficient? I'm quite new to building efficient scripts. Someone mentioned "map()" can be used in lieu of "for i in range(1, n)". Thank you Xero Smith and others for the suggestions of optimising it this far:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul
from itertools import combinations

# Starting from the maximum, we can divide our bag combinations to see the total number of integer factors                                                                                    

def prime_factors(n):
    p = 2
    dct = {}
    while n != 1:
        if n % p:
            p += 1
        else:
            dct[p] = dct.get(p, 0) + 1
            n = n//p
    return dct


def number_of_factors(n):
    return reduce(mul, (i+1 for i in prime_factors(n).values()), 1)


def kinderLevon(bags):
    candies = list()
    for x in (combinations(bags, i) for i in range(1, len(bags)+1)):
        for j in x:
            candies.append(sum(j))
    satisfied_kids = [number_of_factors(i) for i in candies]
    return candies[satisfied_kids.index(max(satisfied_kids))]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Aaron

Comment: What do you think makes it inefficient?

Comment: You can use lineprofiler and memoryprofiler to optimize

Comment: You need to ask yourself a couple questions first : What do you think takes time complexity ? What do you think takes a lot of memory ? Once you've identified this you can go and try optimizing these points. However, often the solution in this kind of challenges is to just do something completely different

Comment: There is a test that has bags = [1, 11, 121, 1331, 14641, 151151, 22, 33, 666, 999] for example. This is a problem, as the algorithm is making all possible combinations of these numbers and storing them in an array. I'm thinking possible a map or yield function may be necessary to stop everything being stored in arrays, as they currently are.

Comment: For starters, cut the runtime of `factors` in half by stopping once you hit n/2, then just add n itself (the only factor of n larger than n/2). Also, no need to build the `result` list, just count the factors.

Comment: Your factors function is too slow. Lookup better methods to find the number of factors.

Comment: After asking a question, please do not update it with given solutions as this removes/invalidates the orignal context which reduces the value for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, combinations are iterable. This means you do not have to convert them into lists before you iterate over them; infact it is terribly inefficient to do so.

Next thing that can be improved significantly is your `factors` procedure. Currently it is linear. We can do better. We can get the number of factors of an integer `N` via the following algorithm:

1. get the prime factorisation of `N`such that `N = p1^n1 * p2^n2 * ...`
2. the number of factors of `N` is `(1+n1) * (1+n2) * ...`

see https://www.wikihow.com/Find-How-Many-Factors-Are-in-a-Number for details.

Something else, your current solution has a lot of variables and computations that are not used. Get rid of them.

With these, we get the following which should work:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul
from itertools import combinations

# Starting from the maximum, we can divide our bag combinations to see the total number of integer factors                                                                                    

def prime_factors(n):
    p = 2
    dct = {}
    while n != 1:
        if n % p:
            p += 1
        else:
            dct[p] = dct.get(p, 0) + 1
            n = n//p
    return dct


def number_of_factors(n):
    return reduce(mul, (i+1 for i in prime_factors(n).values()), 1)


def kinderLevon(bags):
    candies = list()
    for x in (combinations(bags, i) for i in range(1, len(bags)+1)):
        for j in x:
            candies.append(sum(j))
    satisfied_kids = [number_of_factors(i) for i in candies]
    return candies[satisfied_kids.index(max(satisfied_kids))]
```

Comment: This solution is amazing, and gets further than mine does with regards to tests. However, it still fails, which is incredibly frustrating. The disappointing thing is it fails on hidden tests. It's saying the most rigorous tests (that I can see) are taking around 1.6e-06 seconds to complete, so I imagine the threshold for time would be around the 1e-05 mark.

Comment: @alpacinohead welcome to SO, when an answer  helps you, you should upvote and or upvote the answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. As for your question, you asked for a way to speedup your implementation, that is what was done. It might be the case that you need to develop a different algorithm and that is a different matter.

Comment: You are correct. I did ask for help speeding up my algorithm, and that is indeed what you have done. I'll mark this as the correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: Using this solution and changing "while n != 1" to "while n !=1 and p < 9973" I solved this challenge. The code was looping through to high a value of p. I should have known this given the problems constraints. Thank you very much for helping me complete my first challenge.

Answer (score 2):

Following my comment, I can already identify a memory & complexity improvement. In your  `factors` function since you only need the number of factors, you could only count them instead of storing them.

```
def factors(n):
    k = 2
    for i in range(2, n//2 +1):
        if n % i == 0:
            k += 1
    return k
```

**EDIT**: as suggested in the comments stop the counter earlier.

This actually reduces time complexity for huge numbers, but not really for smaller ones.

This is a much better improvement than the one using list comprehensions (that still allocates memory)

Moreover, it is pointless to allocate your combinations list twice. You're doing

```
x = list(combinations(bags, i));
for j in list(x):
    ...
```

The first line you convert a tuple (returned by `combinations`) into a list, hence duplicating the data. The second line `list(x)` re-allocates a copy of the list, taking even more memory! There you should really just write:

```
for j in combination(bags, i):
    ...
```

As a matter of syntax, please don't use semicolons `;` in Python !

Comment: This helps, however the code still takes too long to execute apparently. I wish there was something I could plug code into that would automatically optimise for speed (and or memory).

Comment: Well if this existed the challenges would have no point at all. This is the programmer's job. If the code still takes too long, then you need to solve the problem differently

Comment: You're correct, although this wasn't an optimisation problem. The problem was to create a function returning the needed output. I have done that. The issue here is that the solution doesn't meet the execution constraints of the websites interpreter, so I'm stuck having to optimise my solution it appears :/,

Comment: You could also do `k = 2; for i in range(2, n//2+1):`

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehensions. The factors function can be transformed like this :

```
def factors(n):
    return len([i for i in range(1, n + 1) if n % i == 0])
```

Comment: Thank you. I've added this change, however the code still doesn't meet the execution speed required to be accepted.

Comment: you can make this even simpler. `return sum(1 for i in range(2, n+1) if n % i == 0) + 1` for n > 1